# How can I convert from an IList<x> to a JSON string and back?

Tags: c#, json

I have the following class:

```
public class TestQuestionHeader
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int QId { get; set; }
}
```

and JSON methods:

```
public static string ToJSONString(this object obj)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());

        ser.WriteObject(stream, obj);

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
    }
}

public static T FromJSONString<T>(this string obj)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(obj)))
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        T ret = (T)ser.ReadObject(stream);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

I am using these as follows:

```
IList<TestQuestionHeaders> testQuestionHeaders = xxx;
string test.Questions = JSON.ToJSONString(testQuestionHeaders);
var a = JSON.FromJSONString<TestQuestionHeader>(test.Questions);
```

Can someone help me to explain why the variable `a` contains  `TestQuestionHeader`
 instead of `IList<TestQuestionHeader>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `FromJSONString` method returns an instance of type `T`. Your call in your example passes `TestQuestionHeader` as `T`. You just need to supply the correct type for `T`.

You'll need to change that line to:

```
var a = JSON.FromJSONString<List<TestQuestionHeader>>(test.Questions);
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because your passing `TestQuestionHeader` as generic type parameter. Try following:

```
IList<TestQuestionHeader> a = JSON.FromJSONString<List<TestQuestionHeader>>(test.Questions);
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Is there any difference between me returning List<TestQuestionHeader> or IList<TestQuestionHeader> ?

Comment: `IList<T>` is just an interface, and you cannot deserialize into interface directly. You have to find a class which implements the interface, and that's why you need `List<T>`. You could return any other class implementing `IList<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON.NET, the best JSON library for .NET.

See: http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html